# How are camera views handled in fps multiplayer games?

Tags: c, 3d, camera-view

Hi I was completing the movement system in my hobby engine, where I have a fps camera, and I was curious to know how multiplayer games handle the movement of all players, I mean imagine there are 10 people on a server,8 players playing and moving,2 spectating, do they have 10 different cameras with the mouse movement of each player right? Or am I missing something? So for example if I die and I wanna switch my camera to another player that is playing I simply switch my view with his view? Does it make sense?

Comment: "Perhaps it's easier for you, if you simply imagine the truth… There i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶s̶p̶o̶o̶n̶ are no cameras. Then you will realize, that is not the s̶p̶o̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶n̶d̶s̶ cameras that are switched, but y̶o̶u̶ the starting node of the scene rendering graph that changes."

Comment: yes sorry i meant the view matrix,so in my mind for example player x moves calculate matrix x,player y moves calculate matrix y----> player x moves calculate matrix x,player y dies dont calculate but use matrix of player x

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a great resource for coordinate systems](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems), [transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations)

The camera is just a matrix(or a combination), that bends the universe into a single box(what happens to be outside is outside of field of view) by multiplying coordinates of triangles by self, which is then drawn as if its xy corners were the the corners of screen(viewport actually), and z is the depth(if you need it).

Just 16 numbers, 4x4 matrix is passed to the rendering engine(or more, if you pass view and projection matrices separately), that puts the triangles where they end up on the screen. In my own engine, I pre-multiply the view matrix (one that rotates and shifts the coordinates so the camera is the origin, 0;0;0 point, to the **view space**) and projection matrix (one that packs things in field of view to the screen-box, **clip space**).

Obviously, if you want a different camera, you just make the matrices from the camera's position, orientation, FoV, etc.